# How to see all parent child relations?

Tags: apex

Please help to know,  all parent child relations in *salesforce Sobjects*. I am new in salesforce.

Comment: If you are new to Salesforce, you should definitely complete all the admin [Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules)

Comment: List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childRels = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get( 'Account' ).getDescribe().getChildRelationships();

for( Schema.ChildRelationship child : childRels ){
    System.debug( 'Child Relationship: ' + child.getChildSObject() );
}

Try that - just some example code for a single object

Answer (score 2):

you can use Schema.getGlobalDescribe() to get all fields. then you can check which fields are of type reference to get all relationship fields.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(String s : objectFields.keySet()) {
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult lfieldLabel = objectFields.get(s).getDescribe();
            Schema.DisplayType dType = lfieldLabel.getType();
            FieldNameReference = lfieldLabel.getName();
            FieldTypeReference = String.ValueOf(dType);
            if(dType == Schema.DisplayType.REFERENCE) {
                fieldsList.put(lfieldLabel.getName(), lfieldLabel.getLabel());
            }
        }
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm.

There is a resource to know all the properties of salesforce schema.

If you just want to check salesforce schema then you can use workbench.developerforce.com. There in info tab select standard and custom objects . there you can explore schema of all objects.

Answer (score 2):

Seconding  suggestion to use Workbench for this to explore the schema and review an Object's child relationships.

[Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench) is [hosted](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or you can install and run it locally.

You can review an Object's relationships by going to Info -> Standard & Custom Objects, and then selecting the Object for which you want to see relationships.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a graphic representation, you can also use Setup->Schema Builder and select the object you are interested in.

Comment: This is only useful if you already know what the parent-child relationships are.